# How to prevent user from typing in a hyperlink without using contenteditable=false

Tags: html, hyperlink, contenteditable

Below I have a contenteditable div that generates hyperlinks from f.e hashtags:

```
<div contenteditable="true" >
I think StackOverflow is very <a class="hashtag" href="https://google.com">#helpful </a>
</div>
```

However I don't want the user to be typing inside the hashtag therefore tampering it. It also causes the whole text to become blue:

[image]

I already tried using contenteditable=false on the hyperlink, but this doesn't allow the user to delete it when pressing backspace. At least not in Firefox browser!

```
<a class="hashtag" contenteditable="false"></a>
```

Are there any other ways to prevent the user from typing in it?

Answer (score 1):

this is a known and still open bug in firefox [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685445) still open for the last 8 years.

please notice that you are missing " surrounding the false value for this to work like so: `<a class="hashtag" contenteditable="false"></a>`
i actually tried running this on chrome and it worked perfectly.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  I think StackOverflow is very  <a contenteditable="false">#helpful</a>
</div>
```

if you run this on chrome it works perfectly but on firefox you can see that the bug reproduces.

if you'r app needs to support multiple browsers i would suggest trying to go in a different direction. 
you can see a company called GitBook experiencing browser support problems with their app when using the contenteditable feature [here](https://medium.com/gitbook/about-editing-issues-on-firefox-1aa63c9c80d).

to **tl:dr** they are using a JavaScript library that helps develop apps that need text editing called [Slate](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate)  that you can try. they also mention a few other JavaScript frameworks called DraftJs, Quill and Prosemirror that you can also have a look at.
those libraries provide better cross browser support to allow in browser text editing

Comment: Yes the contenteditable=false is something I do not want, it was just an example. i made a typo in the code preview. In firefox it doesnt work at all. Thank  you for your explanation though!

Comment: @IT-Girl so what is the result that you want to achieve? is it the way the code snippet behaves in chrome?